# Laravel 4 passing a mixture of blade syntax and html to a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

On my AnnivesariesController:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $annivesaries = Annivesary::where('year', '>', 2011)->take(1)->get();
        $data = "{{{\$annivesary->title }}} annivesary was held in {{{ \$annivesary->year }}}";
        return View::make('annivesaries.index', compact('annivesaries'))
        ->with('user', Auth::user())
        ->with('data', $data);

    }
```

On my views/annivesaries/index.blade.php :

```
@foreach ($annivesaries as $annivesary)
         <tr>
            <td>
                {{ link_to_route('annivesaries.show', $data,array($annivesary->id)) }}
            </td>
         </tr>
@endforeach
```

But I get this when I access the /annivessaries route:

```
{{{$annivesary->title }}} annivesary was held in {{{ $annivesary->year }}}
```

While what I really expect is something like:

```
Annivessary 1 was held in 2011
```

Please let me know how i can get to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is you are sending blade syntax to view but it won't work because it is converted to `htmlentities`.

Try this in your view `{{ link_to_route('annivesaries.show', "$annivesary->title annivesary was held in $annivesary->year",array($annivesary->id)) }}`.